# Access Project Extensions during task creation?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I created a plugin in `myplugin.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: MyPlugin

class MyPluginExtension {
   String srcDir = null
}

class MyTask extends DefaultTask {

   @InputFiles FileCollection srcFiles

   @TaskAction
   def task() {
      println srcFiles
   }
}

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

 @Override
 void apply(Project project) {
    project.with {
       project.extensions.create("myConfig", MyPluginExtension)
       tasks.create(name: "firstTask", type: MyTask) {
       srcFiles = files(fileTree(dir: "mySrcDir",  // need to access srcDir
              include: "**/*.java"))
       }
    }
  }
}
```

When I create the task I need to setup the `srcFiles`. To do this I need to access the `srcDir`property from the plugin extension. I want to replace `mySrcDir` with the `srcDir` specified in the plugin extensions.

I need this to set the `srcFiles` of the input for `MyTask`. This must be set outside of the task such that gradle can track if the task is up to date and if any source files have changed.

**How can I access properties from the project extension during task creation?**

Comment: Why don't you read this value during task execution?

Comment: @Opal I need this to set the ``srcFiles`` of the input for ``MyTask``. This must be set outside of the task such that gradle can track if the task is up to date and if any source files have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible. You need to create extension, use it and then configure the task. Now you create extension and at once use it to configure the task - `srcDir` value will be always null. That's the way to go:

```
apply plugin: MyPlugin

myConfig {
    srcDir = 'lol'
}

class MyTask extends DefaultTask {

    @InputFiles 
    FileCollection srcFiles

    @TaskAction
    def task() {
        println srcFiles
    }
}

class MyPluginExtension {
    String srcDir = null
}

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.extensions.create('myConfig', MyPluginExtension)
        project.tasks.create(name: "firstTask", type: MyTask) 
    }
}

firstTask {
    srcFiles = project.files(project.fileTree(dir: project.myConfig.srcDir, include: "**/*.java"))
}
```

Comment: In this case isn't ``firstTask`` a general task not specific to myPlugin?

Comment: It's created by your plugin and can by only used when the plugin is applied but will be configured later on.